# Localized string message inside js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

I have mvc actionLink like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", 
   new { id = item.Id }, 
   new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this article?');" })
```

Now, I want to put `@Localized.AreYouSure` string inside return confirm section. How can I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you want/mean:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete",
   new { id = item.Id },
   new { onclick = "return confirm('" + Localized.AreYouSure + "');" })
```